# Countdown timer which has increment/decrement option that can be set by user

Tags: java, android, timer, count, countdown

I’m new to Java language but worked with C language previously. I tried many ways to solve the following problem but couldn’t so I need help. 
I’m trying to do the following:

•Set 5 minute timer (counter) as default so starts when Start_button is pressed.

•If Start_button is not pressed and the user presses  Up_button /Down_button then display timer options on screen; 5, 10 and 15minutes and if the user presses Starts_button it starts to count down the timer chosen.

•While timer is running;

```
  •If Up_button /Down_button is pressed once then reset timer and show previous time setting i.e. 5, 10 or 15minutes.
  •If Up_button /Down_button is pressed again then display timer options on screen and if the user presses Starts_button it starts the timer chosen.
```

At the moment; the timer is working once Start is pressed it counts down the 5 minutes. But I do not know the best way to display the timer options and also start the chosen timer.

Your help is appreciated, thank you very much in advance.

As mentioned above; I’m in the process of learning Java programming so take it easy on me ;-)   and show me the code that you think is best for this problem please

This is what I did so far:

```
public class Test extends Activity {

// Display Counter Variables
public static Button Up, Down, Green;

TextView timeDisplay;
MyCount counter, counter1, counter2;
int state = 0;
int length = 300000; //5minutes
int length1 = 600000; //10minutes
int length2 = 900000; //15minutes
long startTime = 0;
long currentTime = 0;
long timeElapsed = 0;
long timeRemaining = 0;
long prevTimeRemaining = 0;
boolean up_pressed = false;
boolean down_pressed = false;
private boolean timerStarted=false;

Button start;

  public String formatTime(long millis) {
        String output = "";
        long seconds = millis / 1000;
        long minutes = seconds / 60;

        seconds = seconds % 60;
        minutes = minutes % 60;

        String secondsD = String.valueOf(seconds);
        String minutesD = String.valueOf(minutes);

        if (seconds < 10)
          secondsD = "0" + seconds;
        if (minutes < 10)
          minutesD = "0" + minutes;

        output = minutesD + " : " + secondsD;
        return output;
      }


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);


    timeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
    counter = new MyCount (length, 1000);
    counter1 = new MyCount (length1, 1000);
    counter2 = new MyCount (length2, 1000);

    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);
    Up = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Yellow);
    Down = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Blue);



start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (state) {
        case 0:
          startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            counter.start();
            timerStarted=true;
            start.setText(R.string.pause);
              state=1;

          break;

       case 1:
          // pause
          currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
          timeElapsed = currentTime - startTime;
          if (prevTimeRemaining == 0)
            timeRemaining = length - timeElapsed;
          else
            timeRemaining = prevTimeRemaining - timeElapsed;
          counter.cancel();
          timeDisplay.setText("" + formatTime(timeRemaining));
          start.setText(R.string.resume);
          prevTimeRemaining = timeRemaining;

          // resume
          counter = new MyCount(timeRemaining, 1000);
          state = 0;
          break;

        case 2:
          prevTimeRemaining = 0;
          timerStarted=false;
          counter = new MyCount(length, 1000);
          start.setText(R.string.start);
          timeDisplay.setText(R.string.timer);
          state = 0;
        }
    }
});


    Up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            down_pressed=true;

            if(up_pressed=true && timerStarted==true 
                || timerStarted==false){
                //Display timer (increment i.e. show 5min --> 10min ..> 15min)

                //start timer chosen by user
            }

        }
    });


    Down.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            down_pressed=true;
            if(down_pressed=true && timerStarted==true 
                || timerStarted==false){
                //Display timer (decrement i.e. show 15min --> 10min ..> 5min)

                //start timer chosen by user
            }
        }
    });
}


  public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {

      public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
      }

      public void onFinish() {
        timeDisplay.setText("done!");
        state = 2;
       start.setText(R.string.restart);
      }

      public void onTick (long millisUntilFinished) {
        timeDisplay.setText ("Left: "  + formatTime(millisUntilFinished));

      }

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need a new Class for this.

I would simply create a global variable, eg.

```
private CountDownTimer myCount;
```

I would recommend putting this into a method like

```
private void setTimer(long countdownMs, long tickMs) {
  CountDownTimer myCount = new CountDownTimer(countdownMs,tickMs) {
  /// TODO
  }.start();
}
```

If you need to restart the timer you can call

```
myCount.cancel()
setTimer(...);
```

Comment if you need more details :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. I've added the code and said if Up_button is pressed setTimer(10,0) as for the ten minutes but somehow it mixes it up with the previous timer.

Comment: don't forget, the times in this example are in milliseconds, not minutes! How exactly does it mix up the previous timer?

Comment: That is right, it is in milliseconds. Well, when I press the Up_button while the default timer is running it does nothing to the time displayed (and I wants it to reset + show me the time it was set at), only when I press pause it resets it and plays the new timer straight away.. If I press pause again while the new timer is running both timers i.e. default and new timer mixes up and it tries to display both so it gets messed up

Comment: Can you post your full code to pastebin.com? Then it would be easier to find the problem.

Comment: Hi Force, apologies for the late reply. I was away from the PC till now.. I have posted the full code in pastebin.com and called it "Countdown timer which has increment/decrement option"

Comment: I looked at your code, but I don't see it stored as a global variable? It looks exactly like the code posted above. Please include a link to the pastebin post.

Comment: Oh I apologise, I have added the modified code to pastebin.com and the link is "http://pastebin.com/gcTj2h74". You'll see that it goes to the new counter only when we pause the current counter and press Up but doesn't update when press Up button while counter running.. I have to say: thank you for taking the time to look at my code.

Comment: somehow the link is not working so I have put the code in dropbox on the following link http://db.tt/AmjQaVXN

Comment: Try it without the Class MyCount and just crreate a normal CountDownTimer. Maybe this works

Comment: @ Force I have managed to solve the problem with **if** and **else** statements.. I just want to say thanks for trying to help :-)

Comment: You're welcome! If you think this answer helped you with your problem, please mark the question as solved. :)